# Cannot insert data into my mongodb database using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> Blockquote

Hi guys I'm new in mongodb and I'm creating a rest api since 2month ago. But I can't find my data when I insert it in my database and I dont receive an error so. Hope I will find a solution in this space. Here my code....'

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var router = express.Router();
const User = mongoose.model('User');

router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render("user/home", {
        viewTitle: "Insert User"
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    //console.log(req.body);
    insertRecord(req,res);
});

function insertRecord(req,res){
    var user = new User();
    user.nom = req.body.nom;
    user.prenom = req.body.prenom;
    user.adresse = req.body.adresse;
    user.fonction = req.body.email;
    user.save((err, doc)=>{
        if(!err){
            console.log('data inserted');
            res.redirect('user/list');
        }
        else{
            //console.log('Error during insertion:' + err);
            return handleError(err);
        }
    });
}

router.get('/list', (req, res)=>{
    //res.json("from list");
    User.find((err, docs) => {
      if(!err){
          res.render('user/list', {
              list:docs
          });
      }
      else{
      console.log("Error in retrieving employe list:" + err);
       }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The filter argument to [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) isn't marked optional.  Does it behave the same if you pass a filter?

Comment: Have you tried `User.find({}, function (err, docs) {});` ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `GET` `/list` request, while making DB `find` call, you are not passing the first argument.

- First argument in `.find()` is filter documents.
- It is mandatory.
- Pass an empty object, if you want the list of all the documents.

Example:

```js
User.find({}, (err, docs) => {  // I have added an empty filter object
      // Your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your souggestion without satisfaction.
When I validate my forms, it tell me that the data are succesfuly inserted and when I log in my mongodb console and try to view the inserted data, I got nothing.

Comment: Are those logs coming from MongoDB which says insert is successful? Please share these logs & query you are passing in MongoDB to verify.